# ImportError: cannot import name 'LayerNormalization' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization' , getting this error on colab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a Object Detection model using Tensorflow Object detection API & I am doing this on Colab. But when I am importing Tensorflow I am getting this error,I think this is because of the compatibility issues between different versions.
The thing the confuses me more is that, it was working fine previously and i also managed to do few projects,but today suddenly I am getting this issue.

I am using the following versions
python 3.7
tensorflow-gpu 2.4.1

Here's the error I am getting :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-f83c6d50081b> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 print(tf.__version__)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/__init__.py in <module>()
    175 
    176 # Normalization layers.
--> 177 from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization import LayerNormalization
    178 from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization_v2 import SyncBatchNormalization
    179 

ImportError: cannot import name 'LayerNormalization' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/normalization/__init__.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

Comment: how (and why) did you install tf 2.4.1?

Answer (score 2):

It should be `tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization` as per the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LayerNormalization).

Answer (score 0):

take a look here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/normalization/layer_normalization.py
Nothing there is exported to 'normalization', seems like you can't import from there anymore. It is not even a package, the **init** is empty. It is just a book-keeping folder.

Use

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization
```

or

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LayerNormalization
```

Comment: you could look at the files on colab directly. Handy to use the 'file' tab on the left and then download normalization.py and see how stuff is exported. for me the path is /tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.7/keras/layers/normalization.py

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/normalization
edit: I think that is the correct place to look

Answer (score 0):

Your way of importing is wrong there is no module as "normalization" in "tensorflow.keras.layers"

It should be done like this.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LayerNormalization
```

or like this,

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers

def exp():
    u = layers.LayerNormalization()
```

I wish this may help you..

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question :
After looking at several solutions the problem still remained, eventually I had to shift to Tensorflow 2.6 which I do not know why is performing too slow. Prevoiusly it took around 2 mins to start training, now it takes hours just to complete few steps on Tensorflow 2.6. Please feel free to suggest why TF 2.4.1 is facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when installing tensorflow inside a conda environment in python 3.8 on windows 10. I solved it by uninstalling tensorflow and reinstalling with pip inside the conda env. It seems tensorflow does not have control over Anaconda based builds. [See related issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/50004)

Answer (score 0):

Try !pip install tensorflow==2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

try

```
pip install tensorflow==2.4
```

and

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.4
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).